# imagettfbbox no longer works after using chdir(__DIR__)

Tags: php

I'm using `imagettfbbox` to get normalize several lengths of text for a dynamically-generated image.

I'm using an absolute path for the font name. This works perfectly fine.

As soon as I use `chdir(__DIR__)` at the top of my file to simplify my includes, it stops working, and I get the following error:

```
Warning: imagettfbbox(): Invalid font filename
```

I know that it isn't the included files that cause the issue, because when I use absolute paths for those files and don't use `chdir(__DIR__)`, it works fine, and if I use `chdir(__DIR__)` and *don't* include the files, it doesn't work.

Is there any way to get `imagettfbbox` to work with `chdir(__DIR__)`?

---

Edit: here's a code example for clarification

```
chdir(__DIR__);  //Works if this is removed and I use an absolute path for the include
include '../filename.php';

class Foo {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->font_size = 13;
        $this->font_directory = __DIR__.'/../fonts/';
        $this->font_name = "arial.ttf";
    }
    private function getStringLength($string) {
        $font_size = $this->font_size;
        $font_directory = $this->font_directory;
        $font_name = $this->font_name;
        return imagettfbbox($font_size,0, $font_directory.$font_name, $string)[2]
    }
}
```

Edit 2: It also works if I change the directory back, but I'd prefer a more elegant solution:

```
$old_path = getcwd();
chdir(__DIR__);
include '../filename.php';
chdir($old_path); //now it works again
...
```

Comment: Show how you generate path to the file for `imagettfbbox`

Comment: can you show the code you are using to call `imagettfbbox`? Perhaps break this down to a simple code example.

Comment: `$font_directory.$font_name` should not depend on `chdir`. show output of `echo $font_directory.$font_name;`

Comment: @Cheery It's what you'd expect: `C:\wamp\www\httpdocs/../fonts/arial.ttf`

Comment: @user3191820 as you can see, something is replacing your `font_name` from `ariel.ttf` to `filepath.php`. You can compare those string in both cases and check the difference.

Comment: @Cheery Made a mistake on what I pasted, sorry. Let me edit that.

Comment: @user3191820 compare this output in both cases - with `chdir` and without it.

Comment: @Cheery it's the same. Should we take this to [chat]? I don't know how to link to a chat room yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64066/discussion-between-user3191820-and-cheery).

Comment: @user3191820 No need in chat. If the path is the same - the result should be same. Check by the warning message that the problem is in this line, not in another place or another file.